# "Tom suggested (me/I) look for another job."

Tags: subjunctives

> Tom suggested *me* look for another job.
>
> Tom suggested *I* look for another job.

I'm guessing that the first sentence is not correct. Can I use *me* / *her* / *his* in this kind of subjunctive structure?

Comment: You have guessed correctly; not unless you want to sound like a [misquoted Tarzan](http://www.thisdayinquotes.com/2010/03/weissmuller-me-tarzan-you-jane.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this type of questions, I suggest you use a good dictionary.

For example, if you take a look in the [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/suggest), you will see all the possible structures for this verb.

As you can see from the information provided, you can **suggest something (to somebody)** or you can **suggest (that)** + clause ***but***

> You cannot ‘**suggest somebody something**’: [INCORRECT] Can you suggest me a good dictionary?

**suggest somebody** actually means a different thing:

> to tell somebody about a suitable person, thing, method, etc. for a particular job or purpose

So you can say

> Tom suggested **me** for the job.

that means that Tom proposed you for the job. It doesn't mean he was sharing his ideas with you.

With that said, you need to use a *that*-clause in your sentence (*that* can be ommitted, though):

> Tom suggested (that) I look for another job.

So you should use *I* because it serves as the subject of the clause.